# Посчитать кол-во уникальных значение из базы данных

Tags: php, mysql

```
//zhk-id - наименование поля в БД
Испробовал несколько вариантов , никакой не получился :(
1 вар.

$res127 = mysql_query("select  distinct `zhk-id` FROM object WHERE `pris` > '$priceFrom'") or die(""); // distinct должен как я понимаю отфильтровать по повторяющимся значениям. Не сработало

//далее попробовал уникализовать с помощью php

$res127 = mysql_query("select `zhk-id` FROM object WHERE `pris` > '$priceFrom'") or die("");
$row127 = mysql_fetch_row($res127);
$result5 = array_unique($row127) // уникализируем
echo count($result5); // выводит 1 :( хотя значений должно быть больше
```

Какие есть мысли, что я делаю не так :%(

Comment: что значит "не сраборало" для distinct. он обязан был сработать. Но если нужно только количество логичнее было бы сделать `select count(distinct zhk-id)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Сработало следующее с подачи Mike:

    $res127 = mysql_query("select count(distinct `zhk-id`) FROM object WHERE `pris` > '$priceFrom'") or die("");
$row127 = mysql_fetch_row($res127);
echo $row127[0] ;
```